# How to use a datatrigger that needs a static global variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I have a static class that has a static property that I need to set the visilibity of a button.

I am trying something like that:

```
<Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=x:Static vg:GlobalResources.MyProperty, Path=IsAdmin}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
```

Also, in the header of the xaml I include the name space:

```
xmlns:vg="clr-namespace:MyApplication.resources"
```

But when the property IsAdmin is true, the button is not visible.

I have tried another options like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=x:Static vg:GlobalResources, Path=MyProperty.IsAdmin}" Value="True">
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

So, how could I use the global variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Source` property of the `Binding`, i.e.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static vg:GlobalResources.MyProperty}, Path=IsAdmin}" Value="True">
```

Important: `IsAdmin` must be either a dependency property or it must fire `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` when it is changed.

Since WPF 4.5 there is also this syntax for binding to static properties:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=(vg:GlobalResources.MyProperty).IsAdmin}"
```

Comment: Rellay it has to be GlbalResources.MyProperty and path only IsAdmin, but the solution it was to use Source. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a static as you would any other property, i.e. just make it static, or do something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static vm:MyViewModel.MyStaticText}" />
```

I suspect the real problem here is that your static isn't a property i.e. it doesn't have a "get" accessor. No way around that one I'm afraid, it's gotta at the very least look something like this:

```
public static string MyStaticText { get; } = "Hello World!";
```